# Typescript pattern matching with subtype of string literal type

Tags: typescript, pattern-matching

```
export interface Action{
    type: string;
}

    export interface LoadTodos {
      type: "LOAD_TODOS_ACTION"
    }

    export interface AddTodo {
      type: "ADD_TODO_ACTION",
      todo: Todo
    }

export type KnownAction = LoadTodos | LoadTodosSuccess | AddTodo;

function isSomeType<T extends KnownAction>(x: any): x is T {
    return x && typeof (x.type) === "LOAD_TODOS_ACTION";
}


let knownAction: actions.KnownAction = { type: "LOAD_TODOS_ACTION" };


if (isSomeType(knownAction)) {
    let loadTodosAction = knownAction; // load Todos type
}
```

I'm expecting the behaviour above. I want to do this in a generic way so I don't want to repeat if, else statement in isSomeType function.Basically I want to convert string literal type into appropriate type based on 'type' property. My attempt was to do this:

```
function isSomeType<T extends Action>(x: any): x is T {
    type p1 = T['type'];
    return x && typeof (x.type) === p1;
}
```

But the message says: 'p1' only refers to a type but is used as a variable here.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly the answer is: do nothing.

```
function isSomeType<T extends KnownAction>(x: T):T {
    return x;
}
```

Basically typescript will interfere type automatically whenever function with the above signature is called.

EDIT:

```
 let knownAction: actions.KnownAction = { type: "LOAD_TODOS_ACTION" }; // KnownAction type
 let knownAction2 = isSomeType(knownAction) // LoadTodosAction type
```

Comment: isn't this always trivially true?

Comment: I wouldn't expect this behavior. I have .NET background and if you pass an object of type KnownAction  you'll get KnownAction in return. Here you get an exact subtype.

Comment: So here's my confusion. Originally you were writing something that looked like a user defined type guard. I didn't realize that this was no longer a type guard at first. What you have here genuinely does nothing.

Comment: I am trying to convert string literal type into appropriate type without specyfiyng it explicitly. See edit.

Comment: this feels equivalent to `let knownAction2 = knownAction`

Answer (score 0):

Not a definitive answer, but I don't believe you can.

FWIW the recommended approach would probably be [a switch on the discriminating member](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tagged-union-types).

As for your code, you may be losing track of where type information is lost. The `typeof` operator will not be meaningful here. `typeof` is a runtime operation and even if you write `type: "LOAD_TODOS_ACTION"` in your code at runtime `typeof x.type` will return `string` which I expect is not helpful to you. A string literal type means that the only acceptable assignable value is that string, not that a new type is introduced.

So in order to achieve what you're looking for we'd need to be able to get an interface member's compile time type information. As far as I know, there is no way to do this. When there is one, this is possible, but until then I don't believe it is.

Comment: It's not possible to do it this way because type aliases are not available in the runtime.